# How to show that the Hilbert-adjoint operator $T^*$ of a (not necessarily bounded) linear operator $T$ on a complex Hilbert space $H$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I want to show that if a (not necessarily bounded) linear operator $T$ is defined everywhere on a complex Hilbert
space $H$, then its Hilbert-adjoint operator $T^*$ is bounded.

Now given that $T$ may not be a bounded operator, we can't just use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to get a bound for $T^*$. But since we can't assume that $T$ is bounded, is there a way to get a bound on $T^*$?

Edit: I think i have figured out the solution now so we can close this problem .

Comment: Can you give an example where $T$ is not bounded?

Comment: The title and the content don't match. Is $T$ bounded or not (necessarily)?

Comment: T may or may not be bounded. No information is given, but the question is that T* has to be bounded if T is defined on the whole space H, regardless of whether T is bounded or not. Now it may be possible that this question is a typo or a word is missing .

Comment: How do you define "Hilbert-adjoint" for a linear operator which might not be continuous?

Comment: @gerw that is not a problem, it is just that the domain might be different, but the hilbert adjoint always exists if the domain of T is densely defined and we are defining it on the whole space.  So basically the adjoint is still T* where $<Tx,y>=<x, T^{*}y>$ for all y in the domain of the adjoint which are all the y in H such that $<Tx,y>=<x, T^{*}y>$ holds.

Comment: Why don't you post your solution? @Bill

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 'bounded'. Usually, when people talk about bounded operators there is the hidden assumption that the operaotor is also everywhere defined, i.e. the domain of $T$ is all of $H$.

If that is your definition of a bounded operator the your claim is not true. Because, if $T$ is defined on all of $H$ but unbounded, it cannot be closable (that is a consequence of the closed graph theorem) hence $T^*$ is not densely defined and hence cannot be bounded in the common definition of boundedness. (It could still be that $T^*$ is bounded on its domain $\mathcal{D}(T^*)$, but this may be everything - it may even be trivial)